# Set first Item checked of listview using ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

I want to set first item checked of listview as default whenever an activity created. My activity consist of ListFragment which has ListView. The first item needs to be checked. I've write

```
listView.setItemChecked(0, true);
        listView.setSelection(0);
        listView.setSelected(true);
```

above code for check but on activity created it not get checked. kindly tell why and how i can achieve?

Full code:

```
public class LeftFilterContents extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    Get get;
    View view;
    ListView listView;

    public interface Get {
        void getData(int s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            get = (Get) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        arrayList.add("Type");
        arrayList.add("Date");
        arrayList.add("From to Date");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setItemChecked(0, true);
        listView.setSelection(0);
        listView.setSelected(true);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
        get.getData(position);
    }
```

ListView:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add this line :

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

So you will have :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
setListAdapter(adapter);
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);  
listView.setItemChecked(0, true);
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Also, setItemChecked(0, true); should be enough. Get rid of `setSelection()`, `setSelected()` !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
yourListView.setSelection(0);

// updated the code
listView.setItemChecked(0,true)
//yourListView.getSelectedView().setSelected(true);
```

Comment: app get crashed

Comment: my ListView is <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

Comment: updated the answer please check the code and try hope it helps